# How could you manually add write permissions in Android manifest if visual studio generates it?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have came up with an issue where my phone used Android 10 OS and the API 29 doesn't grant permission with current runtime method for writing in from in the internal storage

So I have found that there is a   need to use an old permission for writing in the storage,but since visual studio automatically generated the manifest file I can't really enable it,also tried using the attributes in the Main activity but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can manually add `uses-permission` to your project : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest#permissions

Comment: @SushiHangover https://github.com/xamarin/docs-archive/tree/master/Recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest if you check here VS has thede options and they are generated automatically Also I don't find a way to add a Manifest file manually it is only generated on the debug folder

Answer (score 2):

As documented in [Working with the Android Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest),

you create an `AndroidManifest.xml` in your Android project's `Property` folder.

Visual Studio merges what you put there, into the final AndroidManifest.xml that it creates in bin/Debug or Release folder.